# Supreme Commander 2 - Build Orders

Tags: supreme-commander-2

What's your Supreme Commander 2 build order. I don't just want "6 mass extractors, 2 power and a factory". List of building and units out to the second or third factory, please.

Answer (score 6):

UEF Air Rush:

- ACU:  2 Mass extractors
- Eng1: 2 Mass extractors
- Eng2: 1 Air Factory, then 2 power
- ACU:  1 Air Factory
- Air1: 1 Engineer, 2 bombers, shield
- Eng2: 2 Mass extractors, then 3 power
- Air2: 2 Engineers, Shield, wait for gunship research
- Eng 3 & 4 assist the factories.
- ACU:  Mass extractors, moving towards centre of map.
- Research gunships
- Continue with power, research and air bases. I usually produce 1:4 fighters to gunships vs AI, but you need to be more flexible vs humans.

A nice alternative is to use the Engineers to build all the base buildings (4 mex then air) and run the ACU towards the centre of the map straight away, but you're saving research points for air, not ACU upgrades, so he'll need some backup a couple of minutes in to the game.

Comment: As a side note you can upgrade your structures with research points. I often go for the +20% increased mass and research income upgrades, as well as the one that decreases build cost. This will get your army up and running quicker, although your units will be lacking tech upgrades